# How to overload the add operator to return the length of two string when they are added?

Tags: python-3.x, string, class, operators, overloading

I am trying to create a class diffStr that behaves like str except, when a user tries to add or multiply two strings, the output is the length of each string added or multiplied (respectively).

My code -

```py
class diffStr:

  def __init__(self, str1):
    self.str1 = str1

  def __add__(self, other):
   return len(self.str1) + len(other.str1)
  
  def __mul__(self, other):
    return len(self.str1) * len(other.str1)

x = diffStr('hi')
print(x+'hello') # supposed to print 7 (2+5)
print(x*'hello') # supposed to print 10 (2*5)
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong because I keep getting the following error message when I try to run the code -

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str1'`

As you can probably tell, I am a noob at programming and trying my best to learn. I would appreciate any help in fixing this block of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `x+'hello'`, you're passing a `str` object of `'hello'` as the `other` argument to `x.__add__`, which evaluates `other.str1`, and since a `str` object has no `str1` attribute, you get the said exception.

A better-rounded approach that helps make the `+` and `*` operators work for both `str` and `diffStr` operands would be to implement the `__len__` method for `diffStr`, so that you can simply call the `len` function on the `other` argument regardless of its type:

```
class diffStr:
    def __init__(self, str1):
        self.str1 = str1

    def __add__(self, other):
        return len(self.str1) + len(other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return len(self.str1) * len(other)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.str1)

x = diffStr('hi')
print(x + 'hello')
print(x * 'hello')
print(x + diffStr('hello'))
print(x * diffStr('hello'))
```

This outputs:

```
7
10
7
10
```

Comment: If I did something like ```y = diffStr('hello')``` and then did ```x+y```, then this error would be gone because other.str1 has a value now. Correct?

Comment: Yes, your original code assumes the right operand to be a `diffStr` object, so you needed to pass to it one. With the approach of this answer, however, you can make the behavior of the operand more generic.